# Pass a model to a partial view?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

this is my partial:

```
@model RazorSharpBlog.Models.MarkdownTextAreaModel

<div class="wmd-panel">
    <div id="wmd-button-bar-@Model.Name"></div>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { @id = "wmd-input-" + @Model.Name, @class = "wmd-input" })
</div>
<div class="wmd-panel-separator"></div>
<div id="wmd-preview-@Model.Name" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>

<div class="wmd-panel-separator"></div>
```

I'm trying to include it like this in my `View`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)

    @Html.Partial("MarkdownTextArea", new { Name = "content" })

    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

these are the model classes:

```
public class MarkdownTextAreaModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BlogContentModel 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Post Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Post Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, how should I do this in order to make my partial reusable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your partial expects an instance of the `MarkdownTextAreaModel` class. So do so, instead of passing an anonymous object which would throw anyways:

```
@Html.Partial("MarkdownTextArea", new MarkdownTextAreaModel { Name = "content" })
```

Now this being said a far better solution would be to adapt your view model, so that it contains a reference to `MarkdownTextAreaModel` and use editor templates instead of partials in your views, just like so:

```
public class BlogContentModel 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Post Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Post Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public MarkdownTextAreaModel MarkDown { get; set; }
}
```

then of course readapt the controller serving this view so that it populates the `MarkDown` of your view model:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    BlogContentModel model = .... fetch this model from somewhere (a repository?)
    model.MarkDown = new MarkdownTextAreaModel
    {
        Name = "contect"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and then inside your main view simply:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MarkDown)

    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

and then in order to follow standard conventions move your partial to `~/Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates/MarkdownTextAreaModel.cshtml` and now everything will magically come into place as it should.

Comment: Yay! I'm learning MVC as I'm coding, so this is great insight, thanks!

Comment: My partial expects a long, how can I pass that? `@model long` and I'm trying something like `@Html.Partial("p", new { m = Model.SWhCode })`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)

    @Html.Partial("MarkdownTextArea", new MarkdownTextAreaModel { Name = "content" })

    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```